# How do I say "from now on, every time I hear 拔, I will think of you going to the dentist"?

Tags: translation

My Chinese colleague wrote to me on WeChat:

> 我刚刚拔了三颗门牙
>   I just had three teeth pulled out

I attempted to reply, but I think I totally botched it:

> 从来每一次我听到“拔”我会想你在牙医时。

I was trying to say

> From now on, every time I hear 拔, I will think of you going to the dentist.

I realize now that 从来 should be [从此](http://youdao.com/w/eng/%E4%BB%8E%E6%AD%A4/) (cóngcǐ; henceforth), but the rest of the sentence feels rather uncomfortable to me.

**Question**: How do I say "from now on, every time I hear 拔, I will think of you going to the dentist"?

Being a bit more careful, I came up with this attempt:

> 从此我一听到“拔”那个字就记起你在牙医时拔出牙齿。

Comment: "From now on, every time I hear 拔, I will think of you going to the dentist." I'm not sure what's the point you are trying to make. The sentence is quite 'English'. It seems a bit awkward when it becomes Chinese.

Comment: It’s a new character for me, so whenever I see 拔 in the future and think about what it’s associated with, I’ll only have one memory, namely my colleague going to the dentist.

Comment: Then try: 我今后再碰到“拔”这个字，可能就会想到你拔牙这事。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "从此我一听到“拔”那个字就记起你"
>
> "from now on" is translated as "從今以後", not just "从此" (since this moment/ since that moment)
>
> "记起" means "remember", you should use "会想起" (will think of) instead

~

> 在牙医时
>
> "牙医" means "dentist", which is a person, you should either write "在牙医診所时" (when you were at the dentist's office) or "去看牙医时" (when you went to see the dentist)

~

> 拔出牙齿 should be reduced to "拔牙"
>
> "拔牙" is a common verb

~

> 從今以後，我一听到“拔”这个字，就会想起你在牙医診所拔牙
>
> From now on, whenever I hear the word "pull", I will think of when you were at the dentist's office getting your teeth pulled

It is a good enough sentence, however "你在牙医診所拔牙" is an "image/ scene" in your mind, which is the object for the verb "想起". Therefore, a better sentence should be:

> 從今以後，我一听到“拔”这个字，就会想起你在牙医診所拔牙这件事

*Use 这件事 (this event) instead of 那件事 (that event) because it is an immediate respond to the event you just heard of.*

*Use “拔”这个字 (the word "pull") instead of “拔”那个字 (that word "pull")*

> 從今以後我一听到“拔”这个字就会想起你在牙医診所拔牙的情況/情景

*Replace 情況 (situation) or 情景(scene) with 慘況 (horrible scene) would sound much more dramatic*